# How to set the hidden attribute on a Windows directory in Rust?

Tags: windows, rust, filesystems

I see how to create a *file* with the attribute.

```
let file = OpenOptions::new()
    .write(true)
    .create(true)
    .attributes(winapi::FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
    .open("foo.txt");
```

I also see that [`std::os::windows::fs::MetadataExt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/fs/trait.MetadataExt.html) will return the attribute mask.

However, I'd like to create a directory or set a directory's attribute with the hidden flag. I dug through the `fs::` and Windows sources and I don't see anything.

Comment: It seems you have to use `winapi` crate to achieve it. See [this](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.6/winapi/um/fileapi/fn.SetFileAttributesA.html) function and [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileattributesa) for it